# Sum column numbers won't work on web

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a mysterious problem. I need to SUM one table's last columns. If I do it from Designer everything works, but if I open the web page then "0" is shown.

I just choose insert formula there.

Then hold control down and drop "m2" to this field and double click SUM.

And it seems that everything works, but not.

In web page SUM is zero.

Some pics:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

To create summation of a column,you can edit the view --> go to "Totals" section--> against the column select "SUM".

Comment: Hi, there is no column that i need. i need "m2" totals but there is not

Comment: What type of column is "m2"?

Comment: calculated column

Comment: Calculated column will not show up in list totals. You create a workflow and run the workflow whenever an item is updated and update the M2 column value into a new column.This way you can total the new column value using view totals

Comment: i am noob in sharepoint and last suggestion don't really help me :) maybe u can tell me more ?

Comment: Create a new number column in your list.Create a SharePoint Designer workflow and in the "start Option", select whenever an item is added and whenever an item is changed.Then in the workflow,add the action "Update Item" and update the "M2" field value into the newly created number column.